# Python: Decorated staticmethod receives non-callable method

Tags: python, decorator

I'm having a little problem decorating a static method in Python. I think the following code best represents my problem:

```
def decorator(func):
    print callable(func)
    return func

class Foo():
    @decorator
    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        return

# outputs False

print callable(Foo.bar) 
# outputs True
```

This seems to be a bug. I imagine it arises because when the method `Foo.bar` is passed to the decorator, it is a function, not a method. That is the only reason I can see for it not being callable, for if we decorate a standard function, it is not callable, as shown below.

```
@staticmethod
def function():
    return

print callable(function) 
# outputs False
```

So is this a true bug in implementation of the staticmethod decorator, and/or are there any simple workarounds? I did think of writing a decorator to asign a `__call__` attribute, but I don't know how `callable` is implemented, so I can't gauge the sucess of such a method.

Comment: Note that you must use new-style classes for a `staticmethod` to be callable also on instances, since this uses descriptors.

Comment: To make it work, just change the order of the descriptors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Methods *are* functions. But `staticmethod` objects aren't. They are [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors), so there's extra magic that gives you a callable when you access it as `Cls.static_method`, but this magic can't hide anything when you use (i.e. pass to decorator) `static_method` inside the body of `Cls`. You can't really hack your way around this, at least not cleanly. A much simpler solution is reordering the decorators such that `staticmethod` get applied last - i.e. put it at the top, above all other decorators.

Answer (score 4):

Well, whether you consider it a bug or not, it's [documented](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#types):

> Static method objects provide a way of defeating the transformation of
>   function objects to method objects
>   described above. A static method
>   object is a wrapper around any other
>   object, usually a user-defined method
>   object. When a static method object is
>   retrieved from a class or a class
>   instance, the object actually returned
>   is the wrapped object, which is not
>   subject to any further transformation.
>   Static method objects are not
>   themselves callable, although the
>   objects they wrap usually are. Static
>   method objects are created by the
>   built-in staticmethod() constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my own implementation of `staticmethod` that *is* callable and this seems to solve this problem nicely.

```
class staticmethod(object):
    """Make @staticmethods play nice with @memoize."""

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Call the static method with no instance."""
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
```

This doesn't use the descriptor protocol and as such behaves very differently than the builtin `staticmethod` internally, however in practice it makes functions callable as class attributes, instance attributes, and even as function attributes (ie, if you've wrapped your class in a decorating function, this implementation of staticmethod will still allow you to call your static methods as attributes on the wrapping function).